# PDO接続のみでMySQLがダウンします。

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

レンタルサーバの負荷テストのため、800 PV/秒のアクセスでシミュレーションを行ったのですが、毎回ある程度秒数（30秒程度）が経ったところで、MySQL接続エラーが発生してしまいます。
※負荷テストの実行時間を15秒程度にした場合は問題は発生せず。

アクセスしているファイルはPHPで、処理としてはPDOを使ってMySQLに接続するのみとなります。
※SELECT文の実行はなし

接続エラーとなる原因としては、どのようなことが想定されますでしょうか？
サーバは落ちておらず（ロードアベレージも20％程度）、MySQLのみがダウンするのですが、
この場合、改善の見込みはありますでしょうか？
（my.cnfの設定値の見直しが必要でしょうか？）

なお、試しにDBのみAWSのRDSに接続する設定にして、
同じ処理を試したのですが、同じく30秒くらいでダウンしてしまいました。
インスタンスはdb.m6g.4xlargeでしたので、恐らくスペック的には
申し分が無いと思うのですが、レンタルサーバ側で最大実行回数の制限などが
働いていると考えたほうが良いでしょうか？

Comment: MySQLのログには何か出力されていませんか？

Answer (score 0):

評価観点が足りていません。

- DBアクセス実行側、DB側のプロセス実行状況
- DBアクセス実行側のリソース状況。 （CPU メモリ）
- DBアクセス側のコネクションプールの利用状況
- DBリソース状況、コネクション数の情報

は最低限見ておきたいものです。シミュレーションでとおっしゃっていますが、前段にＷｅｂサーバをたててそこにＨＴＴＰ投げているのなら、そこのセッション数なども見ておかないとまったくわかりません。

エスパーで恐縮ですが、私なら以下の順で疑います。

- 接続側のコネクションプール枯渇（セッションを解放していない）
- 接続先のコネクション枯渇（無限にリソースないので通常上限を設けます）
- 時点でリソース枯渇と前段のセッション制限

普通に考えて、コネクション数って**キャパシティプランニングの重要な要素**になるぐらいリソースインパクトでかいので、どこかで必ず制限しなければなりません。なので、アプリケーション側で適切な管理（ふつうはミドルに丸投げ）しないとすぐに溢れます。これをやっていないと、さくっと受け側でも送り側でもプロセス死にそう。。ちなみに大規模なシステム程、接続数の上限を問い合わせ側のミドルで設けて、そこで待ち合わせさせるようにします。シミュレータとのことで秒800件でダイレクト接続してません？だとすればかなーーーーーーーーり厳しいと思いますけど、システム設計としてそれで大丈夫なんですか？

たとえば、PHPが動くミドルのDBのコネクションプールから接続させずにPDOに接続先直接書いている場合が該当しそうですが、そりゃあふれるよなと思うのです、そんなことはされていないでしょうが、文面だけみるとそれを想定できるので。。。